# How can I store response data in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

My response data like [131,132,133,134,135].How can I store the data in a variable in Jmeter? So that in another HTTP Request I can use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Post Processor JSON extractor with a **Variable Name** and a Json path expression as **$** to fetch whole array [131,132,133,134,135] OR can use **$[index]** to fetch individual values. Like $[0] = 131.

Use this variable name as ${variableName} in subsequent HTTP requests.

Reference [LINK](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), save in variable name as `response` and use it later as `${response}`

You can leave Left and Right Boundary empty (since last version) to get all response to variable

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using left and right boundaries. As a post-processor, this element will execute after each Sample request in its scope, testing the boundaries, extracting the requested values, generate the template string, and store the result into the given variable name